# What's the process to auto-generate `typesBundle.ts` in polkadot-js/apps?

Tags: polkadot-js

Attempting to test some RPCs in development for a new pallet in Frequency, and trying to get them to show up in the Polkadot-JS UI running locally. I finally hit upon manually adding them to `apps-config/typesBundle.ts`, which worked, but I see this is an auto-generated file. What's the correct process for generating this file (assuming I've already updated my package dependency `@frequency-chain/api-augment` to a local version with the new RPCs)?

I understand this is normally handled by polkadot-js devs when new versions of parachain augment packages are published, but I'd like to know how it's done, as it's helpful for local development.